# MySource Matrix - Opinions

Tags: content-management-system, matrix, mysource

Has anyone had experience with MySource Matrix as a content management system? If so, thoughts/opinions/comments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely excellent. It takes little while to get used to how it does things with its asset structure, but it is really flexible and powerful. Simple edit interfaces are great too.

Make sure you give it enough hardware. If you want dynamic content without caching you need heaps of grunt to make it hum.

Answer (score 0):

Hands down the best CMS I have ever used.  We use it on the [Pacific Union College](http://www.puc.edu) website, as well as many side projects.  I am still amazed at all it has to offer compared to other products that are not free.

Give it a good look, and take some time to get past the learning curve, but once you do, it will be more than worth it. :)

Answer (score -1):

I've recently been trying to use it in an organization where many non power users are generating content. - it has many interface bugs and odd behavior, so that many simple tasks (i.e. loading images) often have to be done by an power user (i.e. me).

When you are editing the HTML of page content white space is not preserved. If you where to format the HTML in the WYSIWYG editor, save you changes, and then come back the whitespace you've added will be removed - actually when you switch the WYSIWYG editor into HTML mode it doesn't show you the exact HTML, and does some silly things - like pressing enter inserts non breaking spaces - but doesn't show them until you save and re-enter HTML mode.

it is a number of little details like this which make it generally frustrating to use and disliked by everyone here.

Comment: You are judging an entire CMS by what it lacks in a WYSIWYG editor.  That is pretty sad.  Switch to a RAW HTML div and you will be fine, the WYSIWYG editor is not the best, but the rest of the cms by far makes up for it.

What bugs are you having?  What version are you using?  Bug fixes are provided monthly, if you have bugs you need to upgrade.